# I want to update a particular image on TextArea(swing) ,when I enter a particular Alphabet on my keyboard. How?

Tags: java, image, swing, textarea

I am trying to print particular images(which include some drawn symbols) on textarea when I type a particular Alphabet on my keyboard. How?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a JTextArea since it can only display text.

You can use a `JTextPane` as it supports the display of `Icons`.

Check out: [Auto Replace Smiles](http://java-sl.com/tip_autoreplace_smiles.html). It shows how to replace the two text characters `:)` with an Icon.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking me to do your homework, but still. I will give you only the pseudo code, you will have to write it on your own.

1. Write a `JFrame`.
2. Add a `JLabel` to the `JFrame` (using a label is easier than using a text pane, and it is impossible to use a text area).
3. Add a [Key Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) to either the `JFrame` or the `JLabel` depending on your application.
4. In the handler write code to add a `ImageIcon` to the `JLabel` when the key you want is pressed or whatever.

Cheers!